# Raspberry Pi Filezilla Permission

Tags: raspberry-pi, filezilla

I was playing with my pi server and changing settings. When I tried to upload a file via filezilla I realized that its giving an error (553 Could not create file.). I can upload and create files in home/pi folder but I can't do anything in www folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /var/www/
```

This command worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think on Filezilla you are using FTP? I was getting blocked 550 premission denied. Try SFTP, it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any rights for example in the /var/www folder.

Upload the files to /home/pi and connect with ssh.
Login as user "pi" (and change to user "root" with "sudo su").

Then you can move your file.
"(sudo) mv /home/pi/file.xy /move/it/to/this/place/"

You can also use "sudo" with the user "pi" instead of log in with user "root".

Comment: Is there a way to give user the rights in /var/www folder

Comment: You can change the user of the folder /var/www

Comment: But it is easier to connect with ftp with root user
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48056/login-as-root-not-possible